# C# Deserialization O(n*n) behaviour?

Tags: c#, serialization, binary

I have a serializable class (call it A) implementing ISerializable.

If I serialize about 11K of these in an array (as an array), deserialization takes about 1.3GB of max VM size to read about 170MB of disk image into a 250MB of final VM size. This takes about 5 mins (elapsed time), 4:20mins(CPU time).

If I serialize each of the above 11K objects individually to the same file (along with a count indicator), deserialization takes about 250MB of max VM size to read a slightly smaller (160MB) of disk image into a 250MB of final VM size. This takes about 35 secs (elapsed time), 20 seconds (CPU time).

Any ideas why? Seems strange. Both the cases above use binary serialization.

P.S. If it is relevant, there is a bunch of contained serializable objects in instances of A each of these serialized objects are instances of classes that implement ISerializable.

Comment: O(n*n) is more commonly represented as O(n^2)

Comment: First of all, use a memory profiler and try to isolate the cause in your very specific case. It's hard to tell generally.

Comment: Yes, I would like to do that. Currently we don't have any profilers.

Comment: Go grab some free trial, should be enough for getting a first insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would presume that the incremental serialization process takes less time than serialization of the entire.array, as this incremental process creates short-lived objects. I.e when each object serialization is complete those objects created in the serialization process are no longer referenced, whereas I would imagine serialization of the entire array leads to a number of objects being referenced for longer. The .net garbage collector is optimized for objects that have a short life time and many of these objects are mostly kept in the cpu cache until a.generation 0 collection.

I would recommend getting a memory profiler and working out what the problem is. I've used the ANTS memory profiler in the past, and can recommend it.

Comment: Do you mean in the 'deserialization process'? I am talking about deserialization above not serialization. I would hope that all the objects created in the deserialization process remains active and don't get garbage collected. On the other hand, if the temporary transient objects created are about 5 times the size of the objects on disk, then everything makes sense. Still working on the profiler.

Comment: Seems like it has to do with Dictionaries and the way they are serialized. Each of my objects had a few dictionaries, if I custom serialized the dictionaries as 2 arrays, the issue seems to go away. Very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the dot net serialization code that causes N^2 behavior: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxremoting/thread/442e95eb-683e-45c3-b84e-25b0b4037d75/#442e95eb-683e-45c3-b84e-25b0b4037d75

Comment: Interesting find but one man's bug is another man's intended implementation. Perhaps we shall refer to it as a "less than optimal implementation"! :)

Comment: Don't be absurd. No-one *decides* to produce dismal performance. It's a bug. "Less than optimal" describes any algorithm that isn't provably optimal. That would be damn near everything. It's not useful in any way to say something like that. I prefer to leave weaselling to lawyers and salesmen.